# Single or Multiple Repositories pointing to same model

Tags: architecture, model, repository, solid-principles

While seeing lot of advises that you should use Repositories, I never seen suggestions on how to implement them.

The problem is that while working on a Game I had a `TeamRepository` where it fetches data from `Team` model and returns them wherever I have to consume it.

While the projects gets bigger and bigger this happens to that Repository as well, and I ended up with almost 20 methods, and this way I think I was breaking the Single Responsibility Principle even though the repository was responsible only to fetch and send data to Model.

So it is better to have 2 Repositories, eg `TeamRepository` and `FormationRepository`, where `Team` model had an attribute **Formation** and there is a **Class** which handles the Formation creation but I needed a Repository to make Persistence and to Construct the `Formation` object.

Or it is just fine to have as many methods as you need on a single Repository as long as they only handle data Fetching and Saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have two different data entities, no matter the relationship between them, you should have two different Repositories that make data manipulations with their respective entities.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a `FormationRepository` object in `TeamRepository` I mean aggregation, and move those methods relevant to Formation into the class `FormationRepository` this way code becomes better. And making  `FormationRepository` class to fetch and return Formations can Ensure SRP on formation repository class. And also Abstraction is being violated if you dont have `FormationRepository` class, Since all the real time entities should be considered an Object.

Comment: Why should I couple TeamRepository with FormationRepository ?

Comment: Because you said Team model have an Attribute Formation So if you want to fetch data from Team model using TeamRepository repository you in turn should also handle Formation object hence ,  If my understanding is correct  you will need a FormationRepository inside a TeamRepository object.

Comment: Yes, the Attribute Formation is on Team model, but coupling 2 repositories wouldn't be a good idea, first of all it will be a pain in the ass to DI when consuming and testing would get tricky.After some conversation with a mate I decided that using another Repo pointing to the same model is fine and the best way to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if you want/need to follow any particular pattern, but given the complain for growing repositories (ie junior [god objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)) and fact you tagged the question with [solid principles](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2009/02/11/solid-development-principles-in-motivational-pictures/) I would suggest the following.

While [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is widely advertised indeed - I don't think it suggests storing all methods in one object but focuses on addition of an abstraction layer between data and using layer. This is why it would be good to follow the repository pattern and single responsibility principle and have separate objects for different methods. For example:

```
public class UserSearcher : IUserSearcher
{
    public User SearchForUserByName(string name)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
public class UserUpdater : IUserUpdater
{
    public bool CreateOrUpdateUser(DTOUser user)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In same cases though however it might be better to have [facade class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), for example ISession object of nHibernate.   It would still keep the single responsibility (ie just serve as facade) while breaking just interface segregation principle to keep the repository pattern intact.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepositroy
{
    public UserRepository (IUserSearcher userSearcher, IUserUpdater userUpdater) 
    {
         // initialization
    }
    public User SearchForUserByName(string name)
    {
        return _userSearcher.SearchForUserByName(name);
    }
    public bool CreateOrUpdateUser(DTOUser user)
    {
        return _userSearcher.CreateOrUpdateUser(user);
    }
}
```

Note that facade requires no logic kept in the facade object and so pretty much is amending of the previous point.

If I had to choose I would go for the intact SOLID principles - it makes the coding fun and solid.

Comment: Without trying to be ignorant, but this solution seems only a refactor one as the design and coupling issue still lives within.